# How to remove highlight group?

Tags: vim

I'm trying to remove the jsonCommentError highlight group. On startup I see the highlight group is active by running `:hi jsonCommentError`.

```
:hi jsonCommentError
jsonCommentError xxx links to Error
```

I tried to remove it with `:hi clear jsonCommentError` and `:hi jsonCommentError NONE` but this didn't work, and there is no change when I run `:hi jsonCommentError`.

I guess `:hi clear` didn't work because the highlight group wasn't added by the user, but I don't know why `:hi NONE` didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't really remove the group. Only to make it transparent.

`hi clear` removes group's own highlighting colors. `hi link` sets group's link target (that always has a preference over group's own colors).

Which one you need, it depends. But it never hurts to do both at the same time:

```
hi clear jsonCommentError
hi! link jsonCommentError NONE
```

Also in this case, you may want to switch off all error highlighting at once (see `:h json.vim`):

```
let g:vim_json_warnings = 0
```